# Weird state issue, setting wrong value

Tags: reactjs

When the below code is executed the alrt box shows the correct message, but the value in msg state is showing incorrectly (green text on the page)

```
await axios
    .post('http://localhost/api/login/', user)
    .then((Resp) => {
        if (Resp.data.code === '200') {
            let User = JSON.stringify(Resp.data);
            let LoginStamp = +new Date();
            let _token = Resp.data._token;

            sessionStorage.setItem('User', User);
            sessionStorage.setItem('LoginStamp', LoginStamp);
            sessionStorage.setItem('_token', _token);

            SetUser();
            setMsg('Logged in, redirecting');
            navigate('/');
        } else {
            sessionStorage.clear();
            let MSG ='Unable to login, please check the following:\r\n\r\n' + Resp.data.message;
            setMsg('Logged in, redirecting');
            alert(MSG);
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

[image: Snippet of issue]

Comment: Alert is synchronous, so it's blocking, no other code will execute until it's been dismissed. Try `console.log` instead and open your browser tools for debugging purposes - don't use `alert`.

Comment: you have added `setMsg('Logged in, redirecting');` in else also.

Comment: @RahulSharma ........ *facepalm* I'm an idiot.  Post as the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `setMsg('Logged in, redirecting');` in the else block also. remove that it'll solve your issue.